# Update the Fragment's UI dynamically after onLoadFinished from AsyncTaskLoader - Not able to obtain ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Previously, I have a `Fragment`, which update its UI based on time consuming fetch data.

```
public class HomeMenuFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Infos arg1 = performTimeConsumingDataStructureLoading();

        // Add in various UI views in v, according to information in loaded
        // data structure.
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_menu, container, false);
        // ...
        // Adding several LinearLayout and TextView into v, based on
        // information from loaded data structure (arg1)
        // ...
        return v;
    }
    ....
}
```

**This is really not a good design.** As sometimes, `performTimeConsumingDataStructureLoading` might take more than 5 seconds, and I will get ANR (Application Not Responding)

By referring http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html, I end up with better solution. The example I encounter is, it updates its UI indirectly through an `ArrayAdapter`.

```
public class HomeMenuFragment extends SherlockFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<HomeMenuFragment.Infos> {
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Infos> arg0, Infos arg1) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater(null);
        ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)this.getView().getParent();
        // Remove previous old views, as onLoadFinished might be triggered
        // by onContentChanged too.
        container.removeAllViews();

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_menu, container, false);
        // ...
        // Adding several LinearLayout and TextView into v, based on
        // information from loaded data structure (arg1)
        // ...
        container.addView(v);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }     
    ....
}
```

I do not have an `ArrayAdapter` as I'm not using `ListFragment`. What I want to do is adding few `TextView` into few `LinearLayout`. Then, I will add `LinearLayout` to the `Fragment`'s container.

However, the following code gives me null pointer exception.

```
ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup)this.getView().getParent();
```

What I know what is the correct way to update Fragment UI dynamically, after `onLoadFinished` from `AsyncTaskLoader`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, most example I encounter is, they update their UI indirectly
>   through an ArrayAdapter.

Using a `Loader` doesn't require that you must use a `ListView`, you can update whatever view you target in your application.

> What I know what is the correct way to update Fragment UI dynamically,
>   after onLoadFinished from AsyncTaskLoader?

Get a reference to the container from the `Fragment`'s view where you'll place the extra views and add the new views.

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Infos> arg0, Infos arg1) {      
    // for some reason the fragment's view isn't built yet so abort things 
    if (getView() == null) {
         ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.containerId);
         ViewGroup container = getViewcontainer.removeAllViews();
         // ...
         // Adding several LinearLayout and TextView into v, based on
         // information from loaded data structure (arg1)
         // ...
         container.addView(v);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_menu, container, false);;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Before returning from `onCreateView`, I can confirm the View inflated from R.layout.home_menu is a ScrollView (Correct. As the root of home_menu XML is ScrollView). However, when I call getView in onLoadFinished, I'm getting `android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout`. May I know what is the proper way for me to get the ScrollView?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng You don't simply use `getView()`. You assign an id to the `ViewGroup` where you want to place the views(I used `R.id.containerId`) and you look for that view(with `findViewById()` on `getView()`) to add the extra views.

Comment: ok. thanks for the technique. i thought i need to provide container and all its UI elements within `onLoadFinished`. In fact, I can just provide container in `onCreateView`, and then add in new UI elements through `onLoadFinished`

Answer (score 0):

For a while I was also trying to achieve the same. Based on the above answer, what worked for me was this:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);

    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_oam);

    if (container != null) {
        if (adapter.getCount() == 0) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Count is: " + adapter.getCount());
            container.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Count is: " + adapter.getCount());
            container.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }   
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Container is null");
    }
}
```

And my Layout xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:background="#FFF">    
<fragment
    android:name="com.myapp.OAMCursorLoader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_oam">
</fragment>
```

Now when ContentResolver updates the cursor and onLoadFinished checks if the cursor is empty or has some content in it, based on this background of the visible screen, i.e. ListFragment is changed.

You can play around with background settings, use a drawable image instead of colors, it is up to you.